# How to update an element of an array of strings on Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update an element of an array inside my model. It's a simple array of Strings. When I run the code, the element is updated, but it's inserting a new array with the value 'newType'. I'm using mongoose 4.11.7.

The result I expect is:
['a', 'b', 'newType'] but after the update it's returning ['a', 'b', ['newType']].

```
const profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: 1,
    types: 'oldType'
}, {
   $set: {
       'types.$': 'newType'
   }
});
```

My Model is:

```
const schema = new Schema({
    types: [{
        type: String,
        trim: true
    }]
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    collection: 'Profile'
});
```

Comment: What does your Mongoose mapping look like? Your query works for my test case: `db.getCollection('test').insert({
    "types" : [ 
        "oldType", 
        "test", 
        "foo"
    ]
})` and then `db.getCollection('test').update(
    {
        "types": "newType"
    },
    {
        $set: {
            "types.$": "oldType"
        }
    }
)`

Comment: I just noticed that my query works on MongoDb directly, but not with mongoose